# How can I use multiple images in my splash screen for react-native

Tags: image, react-native, splash-screen

I am stuck trying to use two different images in my splash screen using react native. I am using react-native-bootsplash library, but I don't have any clue how to make it work, or even start with this. if anyone have a small example or code snippet to see how can I start working on this, I`ll be really grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Just use photoshop and create one image out of the multiple images you have.
Then have it as the one image to use with react-native-bootsplash